# How to pass parameter inside function and get in click in angular?

Tags: angular

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'project';
  getName(name) 
  {
    alert(name);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="getName('tony')">click me</button>
```

I am new in angular and I am using version 12.1.4. Now, What happens here if I simply using click event without passing parameters inside `getName()` and `alert("anything")` then it works perfectly.
But when I try to pass parameters inside the function and assign value in my `click` event function. Then it throws an error i.e. `Parameter 'name' has implicitly had an 'any' type`. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to specify the type of the parameter.

```
 getName(name : any) 
  {
    alert(name);
  }
```

... or as a string.

Answer (score 2):

This is a TypeScript error you need to specify the type of the parameter you are passing to the method and also method return type if it has `void` otherwise.

In your case you are passing the name that means it would be string so add the string type i.e

```
getName(name : string): void {
   alert(name);
}
```